# If an event $A$ is independent of the event $B, B\cap C \text{ and } B \cup C.$ Then find $P(A \cap C)$

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

> If an event $A$ is independent of the event $B, B\cap C \text{ and } B
>  \cup C.$ Then find $P(A \cap C)$.

**My attempt**

- List item event $A$ is independent of the event $B.$

$\therefore P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$

- List item event $A$ is independent of the event $B\cap C.$

$\therefore P(A\cap (B \cap C))=P(A)\cdot P(B \cap C)$

- List item event $A$ is independent of the event $B\cup C.$

$\therefore P(A\cap (B \cup C))=P(A)\cdot P(B \cup C)$

But I am not able to conclude the expression for $P(A \cap C).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\cap C=[A\cap (B\cup C)\setminus (A\cap B)] \cup (A \cap (B\cap C))].$$ Hence, $$P(A\cap C)=P(A\cap (B\cup C))-P(A\cap B)+P(A \cap (B\cap C))$$ $$=P(A)P(B\cup C)-P(A)P(B)+P(A)P(B\cap C)=P(A)P(C).$$

I have used the following: $P(E\setminus F)=P(E)-P(F)$ if $F \subseteq E$ and $P(E\cup F)=P(E)+P(F)$ if $E\cap F=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$P(A\cap C)\\=P(A\cap(B\cup C))-P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B\cap C)\\=P(A)P(B\cup C)-P(A)P(B)+P(A)P(B\cap C)\\=P(A)\big(P(B\cup C)-P(B)+P(B\cap C)\big)\\=P(A)P(C).$$